# What is the purpose of each folder under /Library and /System in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, operating-systems

I'm interested in learning more about the purpose of each folder underneath /System and /Library.

Some are more obvious than others.  /System/Library/Fonts are a basic set of fonts for the system, and /Library/Fonts are any additional fonts available system-wide.  But what's the difference between Frameworks and PrivateFrameworks?  Can I do anything with the packages under /Library/Receipts?  If I install a new app, where under /Library might I find the different dependencies of that app (Frameworks, Extensions, anything else?)

I suppose I'm really just looking for a list of every standard folder under /System and /Library along with a few sentences about what it is for and what might be found inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mac OS X file system hierarchy is covered in great detail in in the Mac Dev Center article, [**Introduction to the File System Overview**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/BPFileSystem.html). Pages you'll be most interested in are [**File System Domains**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/Domains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002281-CJBHIHFF) and [**The Library Directory**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFileSystem/Articles/LibraryDirectory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002282-BAJHCHJI).

Comment: A-ha, for some reason I didn't even think about using the developer documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: That link is dead - I'm guessing you might have pointed to [OS X Library Directory Details](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/MacOSXDirectories/MacOSXDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH10-SW1)

Answer (score 4):

The user and system Library folders, [from Apple's Mac Dev Centre](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/MacOSXDirectories/MacOSXDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH10-SW1):

- Application Support: Contains application data and support files, under subdirectories named for each app
- Assistants: Contains utilities that assist in configuration
- Caches: Contains cached data
- ColorPickers: Contains color picker palettes, available to all applications
- ColorSync: Contains ColorSync profiles, which are used for color management
- Components: Contains system bundles
- Contextual Menu Items: Contains contextual menu plugins
- Documentation: Contains the system help files
- Extensions: Contains drivers and kexts
- Favorites: Contains file aliases
- Fonts: Contains font files
- Frameworks: Contains shared frameworks and libraries
- Internet Plug-ins: Contains plugins to display content in web browsers
- Keyboards: Contains keyboard definitions
- Logs: Contains log files
- Mail: Contains user's mailbox
- PreferencePanes: Contains plugins for the System Preferences application
- Preferences: Contains user preferences
- Printers: Contains print drivers
- QuickTime: Contains QuickTime plugins
- Screen Savers: Contains screen savers
- Scripting Additions: Contains AppleScript plugins
- Sounds: Contains system alert sounds
- StartUpItems: Contains scripts and applications to be run on startup
- Web Server: Contains the Apache web server root